# Pythagorean triples and primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, triangles, pythagorean-triples

> Determine whether there are any right-angled triangles with integer lengths such that the
> lengths of both of the sides adjacent to the right angle are primes.

This was the question I was asked by my teacher.  My first answer is no, which I still believe is correct, but then she asked me "why?" and I got stumped.  My first thought was that Pythagorean triples can be generalized as:
$$2k,\quad k^2-1,\quad k^2+1$$
Is this generalization correct? Because, if so, $2k$, for $k > 1$, cannot be a prime as it is divisible by $2$.  Even if $k= 1$, there are no Pythagorean integer triples that have $2$.

Also, $k^2-1$ cannot be a prime, for $k > 2$, because it can be factored like this:
$(k+1)(k-1)$
Even if $\quad k = 2,\quad 2k = 4,\space k^2-1=3, \space k^2+1 = 5.\quad$  Thus, the two sides adjacent to the right angle would be 3 and 4, one of which (4) is not prime.

Only $k^2+1$ could be prime, proving that either a or b can be prime, but both can't.

Is this proof correct? If the generalization is wrong, the proof is also flawed.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  If $a,b$ are both odd then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$.  There's no need to rely on the parametrization of Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @lulu So... All primes are odd except 2.  If a or b was 2, the triangle is impossible since there are no integer Pythagorean triples containing 2.  Would it be fair to assume that no square numbers are 2(mod 4) or is there a non-assumption method?  I can't think of another way, other than assuming.

Comment: The square of an even number is divisible by $4$.  The square of an odd number is $1\pmod 4$.

Comment: The key point here is that $2$ is not a *quadratic residue* mod $4$, which means it is not the remainder of any square number mod $4$. You can see this yourself by checking that $0^2=0,1^2=1,2^2=0,3^2=1$ mod $4$, exhausting all four possibilities --- since the residue class of $x^2$ depends only on that of $x$. You can do the same with any other mod other than $4$. This idea of quadratic residues is a very powerful tool in number theory.

Comment: Thank you @lulu

Comment: Thank you @YiFan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=2$ and $b\ge 2$ is prime, we need an integer $c$ with $c^2=b^2+2^2$. As $(b+1)^2=b^2+2b+1>b^2+4$, we’d need $b^2<c^2<(b+1)^2$, which is impossible.

Hence we must have odd sides $a=2r+1$ and $b=2s+1$, so
$$\tag1c^2=(2r+1)^2+(2s+1)^2
=4(r^2+r+s^2+s)+2,$$
a number that is even, but not a multiple of $4$. If $c$ is odd, then $c^2$ is odd; and if $c$ is even, $c^2$ is a multiple of $4$.  Neither of these options is compatible with $(1)$, hence no solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

The most referenced and accepted way of generating Pythagorean triples is by using Euclid's formula
$\quad (A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2)
\quad m,k\in\mathbb{N}\quad $ as it produces a subset including all "primitive" triples, $\space GCD(A,B,C)=1,\space$ the only ones considered interesting.$\space\space$  Imprimitives contain no primes. We can reason that side-B cannot be prime unless $\space B=2\space$ and that this cannot be true because the smallest triple is
$\space (3,4,5).$

We can more strongly reason that $\space B\not\in\mathbb{P}\space$ because, in all Pythagorean triples,
$\quad A=2x+1,\space B=4y,\space C=4z+1\quad x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}.\quad $ To visualize this, consider a table of sets of triples that includes all primitives generated by a variation of Euclid's formula:

\begin{align*}
&A=\space\space(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\space&&=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\ 
&B=2(2n-1+k)k\space    &&=&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ 
&C=\space\space(2n-1+k)^2+k^2\space&&=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{align*}

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5    \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89  \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221\\ \hline
\end{array}

Side-A can be prime in $\space Set_1\space$ such as when
$A\in\{3,5,7,11,13,\cdots\space$ but $\space n>1\implies A\not\in\mathbb{P}\space\space  $because
$\space (2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k=(2 n - 1) (2 k + 2 n - 1)
\longrightarrow\space$
$\space n>1\implies (2n-1)\in\{3,5,7,9,\cdots\}
\implies$ side-A is composite.

$\text{Side-} B\not\in\mathbb{P}\space$ because
$ 2(2n-1)k +2k^2=2 k (k + 2 n - 1),\space 2 k\implies B\text{ even 
 and } 
(k + 2 n - 1)\ge 2\implies B\ge4. \quad$
Side=C can be prime such as when
$\space C\in\{5,13,17,29,37,41,53,61,\cdots\}.\quad $

Side-A and side-C can both be prime but side-B is always composite.

$\therefore\quad$ The sides adjacent to the right angle cannot both be primes.